# Save packery gird items default positions

Tags: jquery-ui, grid, draggable, packery

I need to save the default positions of the grid items on a button click.
I'm able to save and reload the grid items. but, after resetting the grid items, if I hit F5 it is taking me back to previous grid positions.

I want to save default positions on a click. please help.

thanks in advance.

// I'm not able to save the default grid positions after this line of code.
**$grid.packery('reloadItems');**

Comment: all I want is, save pre-dragged position on button click.

please help,
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the "stamp" option for Packery. From Packery's docs:

> Packery will layout items around stamped elements.
>   The stamp option stamps elements only when the Packery instance is
>   first initialized. You can stamp additional elements afterwards with
>   the stamp method.

Have a look at [this guide](https://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#stamp) for more details and instructions.